# Add table to query

Tags: postgresql

I have query where I select `id_categories` and `categories_names`, now I added new table `categories_description`, same as `categories_names` but with descriptions (of course it has `id_category` too), how to modify this query to select  `k.id_category`, `kn.name` and my new `category_description` from my new table `categories_descriptions` (sometimes there is no description for category).

```
SELECT
 c.id_category,
 cn.name,
FROM
 categories c,
 categories_names cn
WHERE
 c.id_category = cn.id_category
```

I am using PostgreSQL but I think in MySQL it will be the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [postgresql join 2 tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799556/postgresql-join-data-from-3-tables)

Comment: @MichaelDibbets nah its not the same, I need to select from 3 tables not 2.

Comment: updated the link, forgot to update the text. still a duplicate. And 2 tables or 3 tables joining is exactly the same as 10 tables joining...

Comment: left join != inner join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that sometimes the description is missing so `LEFT JOIN` should be suitable:

```
SELECT c.id_category,
 cn.name,
 cd.category_description
FROM
 categories c
 JOIN categories_names cn ON c.id_category = cn.id_category
 LEFT JOIN categories_descriptions cd ON cn.id_category = cd.id_category
```