# Join 3 tables using ecto query

Tags: sql, select, join, elixir, ecto

Here is a scenario with [Postgres](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=763512)

```
CREATE TABLE "hearings" (
  "hearing_id" int4 NOT NULL,
  "date" timestamp NOT NULL,
  "time" varchar(32),
  "committee" varchar(255),
  "summary" text,
);


CREATE TABLE "categories" (
  "category_id" int4 NOT NULL,
  "description" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  "type" varchar(32) DEFAULT 'normal' NOT NULL,
);


CREATE TABLE "hearing_category_link" (
  "hearing_id" int4 NOT NULL,
  "category_id" int4 NOT NULL,
);
```

Postgres query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(hearings LEFT JOIN hearing_category_link ON hearings.hearing_id = hearing_category_link.hearing_id )
LEFT JOIN categories ON hearing_category_link.category_id = categories.category_id
```

So far I am only able to join current query with one table

```
from h in "hearings", join: hl in "hearing_category_link", on: hl.hearing_id == h.hearing_id
```

But I want to join these 3 tables using ecto and get the results(dynamically would be awesome). [Another similar question but with postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799556/postgresql-join-data-from-3-tables)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to write 2 joins:

```
from hearing in "hearings",
  join: hcl in "hearing_category_link", on: hcl.hearing_id == hearing.id,
  join: category in "categories", on: hcl.category_id == category.id
```